# How to paginate the json data using PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I need to paginate some JSON result using PHP but as per my code its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$arr='[{"sku":"Pizza001","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake-1","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Fruit cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake for Gift","position":0,"category_id":"67"}]';
$raw_data = json_decode($arr, true);
paginate($raw_data,1);
function paginate($data, $page = 2, $perPage = 2) {
   $x = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
   $z = $page * $perPage;
   $y = ($z > count($data)) ? count($data) : $z;
   for(; $x < $y; $x++) {
      print_r($data[$x]);
   }
}
?>
```

Here I am getting always first 2 set o data from JSON object. I need as per `$page and $perPage` the data will be filtered. Suppose `$page=1 and $perPage=2` then the first 2 set of record will be fetched and if `$page=2 and $perPage=2` then next 2 set(`i.e-from 2nd index`) of data will be fetched and so on. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Probably easier to array_chunk with a size of $perPage and then access the $page - 1 of the result.

Comment: Wait, are you getting confused because you've hardcoded your paginate call to always set page to 1 (`paginate($raw_data, **1**);`)? Otherwise, your code seems to work fine? https://3v4l.org/Aereb

Answer (score 0):

I have used a simple logic using  `array_slice` as suggested by Wenchoeng Young Here you go:

```
$i=0;
$page=5;
$perPage=1;

$arr='[
        {"sku":"Pizza001","position":0,"category_id":"67"},
        {"sku":"Birthday Cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},
        {"sku":"Birthday Cake-1","position":0,"category_id":"67"},
        {"sku":"Fruit cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},
        {"sku":"Birthday Cake for Gift","position":0,"category_id":"67"}
      ]';


$raw_data = json_decode($arr, true);

paginate($raw_data, $page, $perPage);

function paginate($data, $page, $perPage) 
{ print_r(array_slice($data, $page-1, $perPage)); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use dynamic variable for the page number and limit your records per page. On click of page number it automatically changes the results.

```
<?php
$arr = '[{"sku":"Pizza001","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake-1","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Fruit cake","position":0,"category_id":"67"},{"sku":"Birthday Cake for Gift","position":0,"category_id":"67"}]';
$raw_data = json_decode($arr, true);
paginate($raw_data, 1);
    function paginate($data, $page = $pageNumber, $perPage = $limit)
    {
        $x = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
        $z = $page * $perPage;
        $y = ($z > count($data)) ? count($data) : $z;
        for (; $x < $y; ++$x) {
            print_r($data[$x]);
        }
    }
```